# Get records as host admin for all tenants in AspnetBoilerplate

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I want to retrieve records when logged in as the host admin for all tenants.

```
await auditLogRepository.GetAll().ToListAsync();
```

This however will not return records for tenants however. AuditLog implements IMayHaveTenant which I think is causing this as anything that implements IMustHaveTenant returns all the records.

How can I select the AuditLogs for all tenants when logged in as the host admin (no tenant)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to disable MayHaveTenant filter to retrieve all logs.

```
using (_unitOfWorkManager.Current.DisableFilter(AbpDataFilters.MayHaveTenant))
{
    var allLogs = await auditLogRepository.GetAll().ToListAsync();                
}
```

[see here for further info](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Data-Filters#DocDisableFilters)